# How to compress ico file on imagemagick or other

Tags: html, image, compression, imagemagick, favicon

I created a 32x32 png in photoshop exported as 500bytes.

[image: favicon]

Converted to ico using

```
magick convert .\favicon.png favicon.ico
```

And it became 5kb.
Question?
Is there there a compression flag in imagemagick or anoter way to compress favicon.ico?

Comment: You are better off exporting to ico from Photoshop itself.

Comment: I looked into the ico file format and BMP or PNG files can be embedded in the ico file: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format). As such the overhead should be minimal. It seems that Imagenagick is converting your png to BMP.

Comment: There exist web sites to convert images to ico online. Maybe one of them will prove better.

Comment: @Tarik wheres the option to export ico form photoshop?

Comment: Sorry, maybe Photoshop can't do it. That said, in terms of compression, the best you can get, is to have your png embedded as is in the ico file. You need to browse the net for a better utility.

Comment: There's an old command line tool called png2ico. But it's a trivial task -- you write 6 byte header, 16 byte icon entry, and then the contents of the PNG file. Shouldn't take too long to write a simple script to do that.

Comment: A short Python script using PIL seems to do a fine job: `from PIL import Image` `image = Image.open('xBaNA.png')` `image.save('xBaNA.ico', sizes=[(32,32)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried @dan-mašek's suggestion and it definitely works better than ImageMagick.

With the PNGs I was working with, ImageMagick gave me a 5.4K `.ico` file despite asking for it to use `.ico`'s support for embedded PNGs for the compression (apparently it ignores you for sizes under 256x256) while Pillow got it down to 1.8K.

Here's how I went about crunching down my favicons based on an existing PNG-optimizing shell script I cooked up years ago:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

optimize_png() {
    for X in "$@"; do
        echo "---- Using pngcrush to strip irrelevant chunks from $X ----"
        # Because I don't know if OptiPNG considers them all "metadata"
        pngcrush -ow -q -rem alla -rem cHRM -rem gAMA -rem iCCP -rem sRGB \
            -rem time "$X" | egrep -v '^[ \|]\|'
    done

    echo "---- Using OptiPNG to optimize delta filters ----"
    # ...and strip all "metadata"
    optipng -clobber -o7 -zm1-9 -strip all -- "$@" 2>&1 | grep -v "IDAT size ="

    echo "---- Using AdvanceCOMP to zopfli-optimize DEFLATE ----"
    advpng -z4 "$@"
}

optimize_png 16.png 32.png

python3 << EOF
from PIL import Image

i16 = Image.open('16.png')
i32 = Image.open('32.png')
i32.save('src/favicon.ico', sizes=[(16, 16), (32, 32)], append_images=[i16])
EOF
```

Just be aware that:

1. `pngcrush` and `advpng` don't take `--` as arguments, so you have to prefix `./` onto relative paths which might start with `-`.
2. `.save` in PIL must be called on the largest image so, if you have a dynamic list of images, you probably want something like this:

```py
images.sort(key=lambda x: x.size)
images[-1].save('favicon.ico', sizes=[x.size for x in images], append_images=images)
```